# Ошибка ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, массивы

Код неполный... При завершении ввода `nameOfCard` в цикле выдаёт ошибку `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. Я знаю, что она делает, но я не вижу ошибки, условие, как по мне, указано верно. Прошу, подскажите, в чём проблема.

```java
BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Input the number of cards:");
String numberOfCardsString = s.readLine();
int numberOfCards = Integer.parseInt(numberOfCardsString);
int []cards = new int[numberOfCards-1];
String []nameOfCard = new String[numberOfCards-1];
String []definitionOfCard = new String[numberOfCards-1];
for (int i = 0;i <= numberOfCards-1;i++) {
    System.out.println("The card #" + (i+1));
     nameOfCard[i] =s.readLine();
     
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо не

```
i <= numberOfCards-1
```

а

```
i < numberOfCards-1
```

Comment: В таком случае если я ввожу цифру 3 например и мне нужно 3 вывода,в вашем случае я получу 2 вывода

Comment: @АлександрЕрёмин тогда уберите везде - 1

Comment: я поставил -1 потому что при вводе например числа 3 , в массиве будет 4 элемента, и при выводе номера карточки будет вывод текста "введите карту номер 0", но теперь понял что можно и без -1 , спасибо Вам большое

Comment: @АлександрЕрёмин при создании массива вы указываете не номер последнего элемента, а количество элементов. Например, new int[3] создаст массив с 3 элементами с индексами 0, 1, 2

Comment: Спасибо большое, моя невнимательность.